# Is "a major years' " wrong?

Tags: possessives

> The government said it would replace the program with a new Immigrant
>   Investor Venture Capital Fund, which will require immigrants to invest
>   money, rather than just loan it. The shift comes as part of ***a major
>   years'*** long overhaul of the Canadian immigration system aimed at
>   choosing newcomers who Ottawa believes are a better fit for its
>   economy and society.

I think ***a major years'*** should be ***a major year's***. If not, how to parse it?

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141101/is-yearslong-a-word

Answer (score 4):

You should read it as

> part of a [major] [years' long] overhaul

The overhaul is big (major) and it took long (years long).

As the comments seem to agree that years' seems weird (I could read it as a possessive, but I have to admit it looks weird to me as well), I guess the best way to write it would be:

> part of a [major] [years-long] overhaul

Comment: Why you changed "years' long" into "years long"?

Comment: Because I overlooked it :) I guess it;s a genitive "A project of many years" -> A years' long project.

Comment: Isn't the sentence looks better without *'s* and with hyphen. *The shift comes as part of a major years-long overhaul of the Canadian...*

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, I would argue that *years' long* is incorrect; *years* is a quantifier and should not be possessive.  However, it might be a standard Canadian or British usage that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @MaulikV I agree. Writing it as *years' long* looks really odd to me. Writing it as *[yearslong](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yearslong)* or *years long* is much better, imho. However, *years-long* is probably the best alternative.

Comment: Although Wiktionary lists *yearslong* without a space, I think I'd avoid writing it that way myself.